# how does the select clause associate each number to its string equivalent

Tags: c#, linq

```
public int SelectWithWhere()
    {
        #region select-with-where
        int[] numbers = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 };
        string[] digits = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" };

        var lowNums = from n in numbers
                      where n < 5
                      select digits[n];

        Console.WriteLine("Numbers < 5:");
        foreach (var num in lowNums)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(num);
        }
        #endregion
        return 0;
    }
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Numbers < 5:
four
one
three
two
zero
```

My questions: how does the select clause associate each number to its string equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

If you want just to obtain numbers lower than `5` you can put a simple `Where`:

```
var lowNumbers = digits
  .Where((value, index) => index < 5);
```

If you want to have *reversed* order, add `Reverse()`:

```
var lowNumbers = digits
  .Where((value, index) => index < 5)
  .Reverse();
```

If you want to query for *each* `number` in `numbers`:

```
int[] numbers = { 
  5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 
};

string[] digits = { 
  "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" 
};

var result = numbers
  .Select(n => (n : n, lowNumbers : digits.Where((value, index) => index < n)))
  .Select(p => $"Numbers < {p.n} : {string.Join(", ", p.lowNumbers)}");

foreach (string line in result)
  Console.WriteLine(line);
```

**Outcome:**

```
Numbers < 5 : zero, one, two, three, four
Numbers < 4 : zero, one, two, three
Numbers < 1 : zero
Numbers < 3 : zero, one, two
Numbers < 9 : zero, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight
Numbers < 8 : zero, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven
Numbers < 6 : zero, one, two, three, four, five
Numbers < 7 : zero, one, two, three, four, five, six
Numbers < 2 : zero, one
Numbers < 0 :
```